# Unable to access website through auto scaled instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-ami

Firstly I have created an EC2 instance and made it a webserver by installing httpd. Later added some content to display in index.html file. Added http rule so that I can open it on google.
Website opening normally with original ec2 instance.

But after creating an AMI IMAGE, Template and auto scaling group, website is not opening through the duplicate instances after opening their IP address on google.

where did I go wrong? Please help!! Thanks.

---

**1.** [Rules given in the security group of original instance]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AFaF.png

**2.**  while accessing the auto scaled instances through GitBash via SSH ->
**Error:**

ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: have you tried accessing the auto scaled instance via SSH to check if the httpd service is up? also make sure that the security group you are using is allowing HTTP access

Comment: @DiegoVelez I have added a rule in security group to allow HTTP access. But couldn't access the auto scaled instance by SSH (GitBash). Is there anything to do with the firewall?

Comment: yes, you also need to enable port 22 (SSH), then try to connect

Comment: @DiegoVelez SSH access was already there. I'm getting an error of "connection timed out" while accessing auto scaled instances through SSH in GitBash.

Comment: could be something related to your networking then, maybe the subnet where you deployed the instance doesn't have public internet access

Comment: Are the instances in a Public Subnet or a Private Subnet? You can only connect directly to them if they are in a Public Subnet and they have a Public IP address. My first guess is that your instance is not launching the web server on startup. You can test this by launching an instance from that AMI in a public subnet (_not_ using Auto Scaling) and then testing whether you can access the web server via port 80.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein oh okay, I will try this!

Comment: I have come across cases in which I had to restart some services when the autoscaling nodes are created. You can add a restart to sshd and httpd service in launch template(advanced details). Also, you can use your main EC2 as a bastion host and try to login to the other autoscaling nodes via their private ips. Are these nodes passing autoscaling health checks(check Instance management tab)?

Comment: @Riz Thanks! I have terminated all the instances and did the same thing once again. This time I have created the template by selecting the instance (Action option) instead of going to "Launch templates" at the left side of the dashboard.